# react native: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I would love to understand what needs to be fixed in useEffect to fix the error described.

here is the "dataSource" :

```
 [{"isSelect":false,
   "selectedClass":null,
   "zoneId":1026,
   "zoneName":"tomato"},
  {"isSelect":false,
   "selectedClass":null,"zoneId":1025,
   "zoneName":"apple"}]
```

```
function Button1(props) {
const [listSelectedZoneIds, setListSelectedZoneIds] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let listSelectedZoneIds = dataSource
      .filter((zone) => zone.isSelect === true)
      .map((zone) => zone.zoneId);
    setListSelectedZoneIds(listSelectedZoneIds);
  }, [dataSource]);

  useEffect(() => {
    eventEmitter?.emit('selected', listSelectedZoneIds);
  }, [listSelectedZoneIds]);
}
```

Comment: What is `dataSource` in your code snippet? Can you share a more complete code example? This isn't even a valid React component. [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: here is the "dataSource" :
`[
   {
      "isSelect":false,
      "selectedClass":null,
      "zoneId":1026,
      "zoneName":"tomato"
   },
   {
      "isSelect":false,
      "selectedClass":null,
      "zoneId":1025,
      "zoneName":"apple"
   }
]`

Comment: `dataSource` is a dependency for the `useEffect` hook that is likely being triggered and attempting to update state *after* the component unmounted. What is updating `dataSource`? Please include a more comprehensive component code example, preferably the *entire* component and any parent components that trigger updates/rerenders, so that we've the full context.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have not provide the **cleanup** function in the **useEffect** function.
There is something which is changing in the data sources and thus useEffect is triggered, but actually the screen is not in focused, you can solve it with the following codes, and read more about cleanup useEffect from the given link:
https://dev.to/otamnitram/react-useeffect-cleanup-how-and-when-to-use-it-2hbm

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    if (isMounted) {
      (() => {
       let listSelectedZoneIds = dataSource
  .filter((zone) => zone.isSelect === true)
  .map((zone) => zone.zoneId);
setListSelectedZoneIds(listSelectedZoneIds);
      })();
    }

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [dataSource]);
```

**2nd** one would be:

```
useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;

    if (isMounted) {
      (() => {
       eventEmitter?.emit('selected', listSelectedZoneIds);
      })();
    }

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [listSelectedZoneIds]);
```

Basically, the above codes will help you to make the useEffect only update the screen if it is mounted in the stack, and if it is not mounted the state is not gonna update till screen mount in stack. **Reffer** to the above link to help understand better why the error/warning is appearing.

Comment: Have you tested this code? Perhaps I'm just misreading it, but glancing it over it seems any time the effect callback is run that `isMounted` is set `true` and the if-statement will be executed. I don't think this pattern really works here because while `isMounted` is set `false` in the clean up function at the end of a render cycle, it is immediately set `true` again when the effect. Nothing in the first effect is asynchronous to take advantage of enclosures.

Comment: The codes are tested, actually react-navigation mostly use the redux in its stack, so it is workaround solution for these types of warnings, where sometimes we don't have any controller to cleanup the function, this workaround is helpful in these cases and can be implemented mostly with firebase/firestore.

Comment: its not works in my case.. i dont know why

Comment: Check all your screens too, and update your useEffect with the above code.